# Qt version is not properly installed

Tags: kubuntu, qt, 15.10

Qt Creator says that Qt 5.4.2 is not properly installed.

[image]

I installed the *qtcreator* package from the Ubuntu repositories. What can I do about it?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

Comment: how did you install it ? Can you post the exact commands you ran and exact error messages you got when installing and running ,

Comment: i don't think i did. i guess it's installed with the distribution.

Comment: QT Creator isn't installed per default. How did you install QT Creator? And what exactly "says" QT Creator?

Comment: i thought the question was about Qt and not Qt Creator. i tried to reply to your comment by changing my original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

installation of `qt5-default` turned the red error icon into a yellow warning one and enabled me to build projects.